# Почему не возвращает массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

10. Написать ф-цию, которая создает массив с указанной длиной и наполняет его переданным значением
    // пример: ф-ция fillArray(3, 'a') должна возвращать массив ['a', 'a', 'a']

---

```js
function fn(arraySize, value) {
    const newArray = []
    for (let index = 0; index < arraySize.length; index += 1) {
        newArray.push(value)
    }
    return newArray
}
console.log(fn(3, 'a'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы не правильно задали условие в цикле. Сравнивать надо index с arraySize, т.к. это число.

У чисел нет метода length

```js
function fn(arraySize, value) {
    const newArray = []
    for (let index = 0; index < arraySize; index += 1) {
        newArray.push(value)
    }
    return newArray;
}
console.log(fn(3, 'a'));
```